# Amazon AWS PHP SDK with Guzzle's MultiCurl?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, curl-multi, guzzle

I need to perform some fairly heavy queries with Amazon's AWS SDK for PHP.
The most efficient way would be to use [PHP's MultiCurl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESiP8R-fvq0).  It seems that [Guzzle already has](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php) functionality for MultiCurl built in.

Does using the standard methods provided by the AWS SDK automatically use MultiCurl or do I have to specify it's usage directly?  E.g. calling `$sns->Publish()` 30 times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel requests work exactly the same in the SDK as in plain Guzzle and do take advantage of MultiCurl. For example, you could do something like this:

```
$message = 'Hello, world!';
$publishCommands = array();
foreach ($topicArns as $topicArn) {
    $publishCommands[] = $sns->getCommand('Publish', array(
        'TopicArn' => $topicArn,
        'Message'  => $message,
    ));
}

try {
    $successfulCommands = $sns->execute($publishCommands);
    $failedCommands = array();
} catch (\Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException $e) {
    $successfulCommands = $e->getSuccessfulCommands();
    $failedCommands = $e->getFailedCommands();
}

foreach ($failedCommands as $failedCommand) { /* Handle any errors */ }

$messageIds = array();
foreach ($successfulCommands as $successfulCommand) {
    $messageIds[] = $successfulCommand->getResult()->get('MessageId');
}

// Also Licensed under version 2.0 of the Apache License.
```

The [AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html) has more information about working with command objects in this way.